# Instantiate and display a ClassifiedAd

Tags: c#, homework

> Create an application named `TestNewspaperAd` that instantiates and displays a `ClassifiedAd` object. A `ClassifiedAd` has fields for number of words and a price. Include get and set properties for the number of words but only a get property for the price--the price should be calculated at nine cents per word. You can create either a console or GUI app.

```
namespace TestNewsPaperAd
{
    class Newspaper
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const double rate = 0.09;
            double total;
            ClassifiedAd Article = new ClassifiedAd();
            Article.Words = 583;

            total = Article.Words * rate;

            WriteLine("The price of the {0} word article is {1}\n", Article.Words, total);
        }
    }
}
class ClassifiedAd
{
    private int words;
    private double price;

    public int Words
    {
        get
        {
            return words;
        }
        set
        {
            words = value;
        }
    }
    public double Price
    {
        get
        {
            return price;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There is an error in how you implement the `Price` property: according to the description your `get` for the price should return the number of words times `0.09`. As it is, the Price will always return 0 as there is never a value assigned to it.

Try adding `Console.WriteLine(Article.Price);` inside your Main method for demonstration.

You can add this inside your class:

```
private const decimal pricePerWord = 0.09M;
```

Notice the use of [`decimal`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx) (including the `M` suffix) instead of `double`, which is a more appropriate type for currency/money values.

Then your `get` becomes:

```
public decimal Price
{
    get
    {
        return Words * pricePerWord;
    }
}
```

---

I would also recommend to make a constructor for `ClassifiedAd` that takes the number of words, since a classified ad without words would be nonsensical.

```
public ClassifiedAd(int words)
{
    this.words = words;
}
```

---

Also as [suggested by Roman Gräf](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/160511/42632), a `ToString` override method would be a nice addition:

```
override public string ToString()
{
    return string.Format("The price of a {0} word classified ad is {1}\n", Words, Price);
}
```

---

Then your `Main` method can do everything by only using what your `ClassifiedAd` class provides:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ClassifiedAd ad = new ClassifiedAd(583);
    Console.WriteLine(ad.ToString());
    // The price of a 583 word classified ad is 52.47

    ad.Words = 900;
    Console.WriteLine(ad.ToString());
    // The price of a 900 word classified ad is 81.00
}
```

Comment: Good answer but consider decimal for price

Comment: Good suggestion, I integrated it into my answer =)

Comment: Upvoted for use of decimal in the answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

### `ClassifiedAd`

Currently `ClassifiedAd` does nothing beside from holding two values. I would recommend to put functionality inside `ClassifiedAd`:

```cs
public double PriceAtRate(double rate)
{
    return rate*words;
}
```

This would also solve the problem that you can't use `ClassifiedAd.price` can never be assigned.

You could also store the words for the Ad inside your Class.

```cs
private string text;
private int wc=-1;
public int WordCount 
{
    get 
    {
        if(wc==-1)
        {
              wc=text.Split(" ").Length;
        }
        return wc;
    }
}
public int Words {
    get 
    {
        return text;
    }
    set
    {
        text = value;
        wc = -1;
    }
}
```

Also you may want to override the `Object.ToString` method.

```cs
public override string ToString()
{
//Whatever format you like
}
```